# How do I prevent Heroku from deleting my Postgress database when pushing to github?

Tags: database, postgresql, github, heroku, reset

Whenever I push changes to Github and my backend rebuilds itself on Heroku, it resets/deletes the Postgress database. How can I prevent this?

Comment: That's not the standard behavior, so it's something in your code or deployment process. Do you run database migrations in your deployments, for example?

Comment: Thanks for the response! No, I'm not running a database migration. At least not that I'm aware of. Still quite new to coding. Is there an easy way to check if I'm running a migration?

Comment: How do you build/deploy code? What language and framework are you using? Does your deployment process include the provisioning of databases, or did you set those up manually in the Heroku console?

Comment: also it would help if you share the link to your repo, if it's public

Comment: Thanks for thinking along ceejayoz! I fixed the problem. Before pushing my application to production, I was using Sqlite. It seems as though I was still using it. Once I turned sqlite of, the problem doesn't happen anymore!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Before pushing my application to production, I was using Sqlite. It seems as though I was still using it. Once I turned sqlite of, the problem doesn't happen anymore!

The working code:

```
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;

module.exports = ({ env }) => {

  if(env('NODE_ENV') === 'production') {
    const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
    return {
      defaultConnection: 'default',
      connections: {
        default: {
          connector: 'bookshelf',
          settings: {
            client: 'postgres',
            host: config.host,
            port: config.port,
            database: config.database,
            username: config.user,
            password: config.password
          },
          options: {
            ssl: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    // defaultConnection: 'default',
    // connections: {
    //   default: {
    //     connector: 'bookshelf',
    //     settings: {
    //       client: 'sqlite',
    //       filename: env('DATABASE_FILENAME', '.tmp/data.db'),
    //     },
    //     options: {
    //       useNullAsDefault: true,
    //     },
    //   },
    // },
  }
};
```